# Change the <label> HTML output by WordPress comment_form?

Tags: wordpress, forms

Is there a way to edit/change the HTML outputted by the function comment_form()? I dont like the HTML thats created by default for my project.

Namely, what I dont like is this:

```
<label for="author">Name</label><span class="required">*</span>
```

I would much prefer to have this:

```
<label for="author">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
```

Ive been looking around the files of Twenty Eleven, but I couldnt find it.

Comment: I would recommend against that as, semantically, it doesn't make any sense (especially for screen readers, which is the main benefit of the `label` tag).

Comment: Im using wordpress 3.3.1

Comment: This is also good for me: 

<label class="required" for="author">Name *</label>

Comment: It's the putting the * inside the label that is a bad thing.  It's not content, it's meta-data

Comment: What I want to know is how to change that. I dont know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a comments.php file in your current theme?  If so, you should be able to modify that as needed and the changes will be reflected when `comment_form()` is called.

Alternatively, you can pass the `comment_form()` with `$args`.  For a more in depth look at passing `$args` just take a look at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form).  In regards to styling the form, take a look at [The Comments Form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Theme_Forms#The_Comments_Form) under Styling Theme Forms in the Codex.